# Issue using MSBuild to build a Delphi Android project

Tags: android, delphi, msbuild

I've been invoking MSBuild to build my VCL projects for a long while now, and would like to add some android projects too. I thought it was too much to ask that my same calls would work on a Delphi XE8 project targeted to Android rather than Windows, but it does seem to get close. My output is below. As you see, it seems to get all the way through the compilation but falls at the point doing something with the manifest.

Can anyone suggest what I might look at to resolve? Thanks.

```
09/08/2015 09:03:29     Building C:\Art_soft\Code\PRT-MS1\Delphi\Libraries\Multiplatform\Delphi projects\FMXCommonUnitTests_Android.dproj

Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.5420
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.5485]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 08/09/2015 09:03:29.
Project "C:\Art_soft\Code\PRT-MS1\Delphi\Libraries\Multiplatform\Delphi projects\FMXCommonUnitTests_Android.dproj" on node 0 (Build target(s)).
  Creating directory "c:\scratch\msbuild".
BuildClassesDex:
  Merged dex A (520 defs/562.4KiB) with dex B (68 defs/120.5KiB). Result is 588 defs/833.3KiB. Took 0.3s
  Merged dex A (588 defs/833.3KiB) with dex B (3 defs/2.1KiB). Result is 591 defs/1078.6KiB. Took 0.1s
  Merged dex A (591 defs/1078.6KiB) with dex B (95 defs/99.0KiB). Result is 686 defs/1624.1KiB. Took 0.1s
  Result compacted from 2556.0KiB to 858.9KiB to save 1697.1KiB
  Merged dex A (686 defs/1624.1KiB) with dex B (87 defs/112.8KiB). Result is 773 defs/858.9KiB. Took 0.2s
  Merged dex A (773 defs/858.9KiB) with dex B (3 defs/5.2KiB). Result is 776 defs/1054.1KiB. Took 0.0s
  Merged dex A (776 defs/1054.1KiB) with dex B (25 defs/37.8KiB). Result is 801 defs/1410.8KiB. Took 0.1s
  Result compacted from 4165.5KiB to 2714.8KiB to save 1450.7KiB
  Merged dex A (801 defs/1410.8KiB) with dex B (1869 defs/1854.6KiB). Result is 2670 defs/2714.8KiB. Took 0.4s
BuildVersionResource:
  CodeGear Resource Compiler/Binder
  Version 1.2.2 Copyright (c) 2008-2012 Embarcadero Technologies Inc.

  Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


  Deleting file "FMXCommonUnitTests_Android.vrc".
c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1315,5): error MSB4018: The "CreateAndroidManifestFile" task failed unexpectedly.
c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1315,5): error MSB4018: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\scratch\msbuild\..\..\AndroidManifest.template.xml' is denied.
c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1315,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1315,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1315,5): error MSB4018:    at Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.CreateAndroidManifestFile.genManifestFile()
c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1315,5): error MSB4018:    at Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.CreateAndroidManifestFile.Execute()
c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets(1315,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.TaskEngine.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(EngineProxy engineProxy, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, ITask task, Boolean& taskResult)
Done Building Project "C:\Art_soft\Code\PRT-MS1\Delphi\Libraries\Multiplatform\Delphi projects\FMXCommonUnitTests_Android.dproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a new multi device project in a new folder with the same names. By the same names I mean the DPR and the first main Delphi form, UNIT1.PAS. Once that is created, try compiling it. After it compiles successfully, close Delphi and copy the files from the original project over to the newly created project. Make sure that only the .DPR, .PAS, .FMX. .VLB files are copied over. DO NOT REPLACE ANY OF THE DPROJ files.

Reopen delphi and the project and you will see that you can now compile for Android.

Regards

Comment: THanks but my question was relating to how to automate the Android build outside the IDE. I have no problem building and deploying from inside the IDE and I do use the method that you suggest.